# UnityでgameObjectのpositonの値を小数点第3に変更したい

Tags: c#, unity3d

gameObjectのpositonの値を小数点第3までをposListsに代入されるようにしたいのですがどうすればよろしいのでしょうか？
現状では小数点第7までが代入されてしまっています。

```
public List<Vector3> posLists = new List<Vector3>();

    void Update(){

    gameObject.posLists.Add(gameObject.transform.position);

    }
```

Comment: これとかどうでしょう。[指定した小数以下を切り捨てたい。](https://teratail.com/questions/50852)

Comment: 強引な手段ですが、floatをtoStringで少数第３位まで範囲指定を行い、float.Parseするのはどうでしょうか